# How can we submit our Android app for review without including iOS app information, given that our new feature only affects the Android version?

Tags: facebook, facebook-permissions, facebook-appreview

Our Android/iOS application is already live, and we've obtained the necessary permissions through the review process. We've implemented a new feature in the Android app that requires additional permissions. However, the iOS app does not require these permissions at the moment. When submitting our app for review, the system is prompting us to provide information for the iOS app, even though it's not relevant in this case.

How can we proceed with the app submission, focusing solely on the Android version?